# replace positions of elements in a string using R

Tags: r, string, replace

I have a string:

```
str = 'Mr[5]'
```

I want to switch the positions of `Mr` and `5` in `str`, and get a result like this:

```
result = '[5]Mr'
```

How can I do this in R?

Comment: Can you show more examples which would perhaps make the problem more clear?

Comment: You have strings like this :  "Mr[1234]", "Mrs[456]" etc ?

Comment: @digEmAll, yes, exactly. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [gsub](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) :

```
values <- c("Mr[5]","Mr[1234]", "Mrs[456]")
values2 <- gsub("^(.+)(\\[[0-9]+\\])$", "\\2\\1", values)

# > values2
# [1] "[5]Mr"    "[1234]Mr" "[456]Mrs"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a regex with 2 matching group for which you change position.
`stringr` package helps with character manipulation.

```r
s <- c("Mr[5]", "Mr[3245]", "Mrs[98j]")
stringr::str_replace_all(s, "^(.*)(\\[.*\\])$", "\\2\\1")
#> [1] "[5]Mr"    "[3245]Mr" "[98j]Mrs"
```

about the regex

- `^` is the beginning of the string and `$` the end
- `.*` matches every character, zero or more time
- `(` and `)` define matching group
- `\\[` and `\\]` match literal bracket
- together you have a simple regex that match for exemple `Mr` then `[5]` : `"(.*)(\\[.*\\])"`
- `\\1` refers to the first matching group, `\\2` refers to the second. `\\2\\1` inverse the groups

Obviously, you can create a better regex that fits precisely to your need. The mechanism with matching groups with remain. [regex101](https://regex101.com/) is a good site to help you with regex. 
In R, `stringr` website have nice intro about [regex](http://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and detailed explanation!!